# Unable to get Email via Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Unable to get email via Facebook login though we get accesstoken, id , name but email as null even permission for email is also mentioned in code,is there anything we have set permission for email too from facebook developer console.
Followed the set as per the [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android),.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private static final String EMAIL = "email";
String Email = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    //loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
    // If you are using in a fragment, call loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Callback registration
    LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity .this, Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.e("Facebook_loginResult", loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Login_FB_Response", object.toString());

                        if (object.has("email")) {
                             Email = object.getString("email");
                        }
                        Log.e("Login_FB_Email", Email);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email, birthday, gender, location");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.e("Facebook_Cancel", "onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.e("Facebook_Exception", exception.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Comment: any error in logcat

Comment: add  loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity .this, Arrays.asList(EMAIL)); in the onclick of fb button instead of onCreate

Comment: private static final String EMAIL = "email";
String Email = null;

...and yo don´t see any problem with that? :)

Comment: @YashaswiNP ya done with that way but same result. email getting for registered developer acct but not for new member even after pointing it to live mode.